# class lookup function python

Tags: python, class, matrix

I have a class

```
class Kaart:


def __init__(self, rows = 10, colls = 10):
    self.rows = rows
    self.colls = colls
    self.matrixRC = []
    for _ in range(rows):
        self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(colls)])
```

and I was wondering if there was a way to get the value of a place in `matrix` without doing `Kaart.matrixRC[1][2]` but by for example just doing `Kaart(1, 2)` or `Kaart[1, 2]` (Kaart is not the initiator in these examples but an instance of the `Kaart` class). I saw there was a `__getitem__()` function, but I am not quite sure what it does, and it doesn't look like it do what I need.

Comment: look into implementing `__getitem__()` (and `__iter__()` if you want to be able to iterate through the items) .

Comment: `kaart = Kaart()` then `kaart[...]` will trigger the `__getitem__` method, passing `...` as an argument to that method. It is *exactly* what you need.

Comment: @Roars I have never used an `__iter__()` but does it work like this
`a = Kaart()`
`for i in a.matrixRC:
 for j in i:
  print(j)`

Comment: you could set the `__iter__()` method for Kaart to return `self.matrixRC.__iter__()`. That way when you do `for i in kaart:` you will be able to iterate through the rows of the matrix.

Comment: @Roars Good idea, I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `__getitem__` works. ;) You should also define `__setitem__`. I've also added a `__str__` method.

```
class Kaart:
    def __init__(self, rows = 10, colls = 10):
        self.rows = rows
        self.colls = colls
        self.matrixRC = []
        for _ in range(rows):
            self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(colls)])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        r, c = key
        return self.matrixRC[r][c]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        r, c = key
        self.matrixRC[r][c] = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(row) for row in self.matrixRC)

kaart = Kaart()
kaart[2, 3] = 7
print(kaart)
print(kaart[2, 3])
```

**output**

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
7
```

---

If we follow [Roars suggestion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548524/class-lookup-function-python/47548672#comment82055773_47548524), we can simplify that `__str__` method a little.

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.matrixRC.__iter__()

def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(row) for row in self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite your objection, `__getitem__()` is the solution here. Use like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.matrixRC[key]
```

Comment: Well, I should have probably just tried that haha, thanks!